Testcontainers and custom network, kafka unreachable
I have the following code snippet for kafka container creation using test containers
    private GenericContainer<?> createKafkaContainer() {
        try (GenericContainer<?> kafkaContainer = new GenericContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka"))
                .withEnv(kafkaProperties)
                .withExposedPorts(9092)
                .withNetwork(network)
                .withNetworkAliases("my-kafka")
                .withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd -> cmd.withHostConfig(
                        new HostConfig()
                                .withPortBindings(new PortBinding(Ports.Binding.bindPort(9092), new ExposedPort(9092)))
                ))
                .withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd -> cmd.withHostName("my-kafka"))
                .withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd -> cmd.withName("my-kafka"))
        ) {
            return kafkaContainer;
        }

I also create a custom network like this at class level
Network network = Network.newNetwork();

When I run my spring boot based test from mac, I get below error:
2024-12-07T21:14:12.895-08:00  WARN 74816 --- [ntainers-wait-0] .c.w.i.InternalCommandPortListeningCheck : An exception while executing the internal check: Container.ExecResult(exitCode=137, stdout=, stderr=Ncat: Version 7.70 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connection to ::1 failed: Connection refused.
Ncat: Trying next address...
Ncat: Connection refused.
/bin/bash: connect: Connection refused
/bin/bash: /dev/tcp/localhost/9092: Connection refused
Ncat: Version 7.70 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connection to ::1 failed: Connection refused.
Ncat: Trying next address...
Ncat: Connection refused.
/bin/bash: connect: Connection refused
/bin/bash: /dev/tcp/localhost/9092: Connection refused
Ncat: Version 7.70 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connection to ::1 failed: Connection refused.
Ncat: Trying next address...
Ncat: Connection refused.
/bin/bash: connect: Connection refused
/bin/bash: /dev/tcp/localhost/9092: Connection refused

If I don't provide custom network, and I use host.docker.internal, things work just fine. What is also confusing is, do I need my ryuk to be on same network and need to do something explicitly for it? I am not bringing up ryuk explicitly, but I know it gets created when I launch my test.

Trying to fix port mapping? In our case for development troubleshooting on local environment we are using testcontainers desktop services to have a proxy on a fixed port. For automated testing we are doing the mapping of port dynamically at runtime.
